# Reading a .doc (MSWord) file in ObjectiveC?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ms-word

Is it possible to read a .doc (MSWord) file in ObjC ?
   Or 
   Is there any other way to read the word file ?

Thanks

Comment: Please: Objective-C is a language, not a platform or a framework...

Comment: A lot of languages come with reasonably rich standard libraries, so this way of phrasing the question is common: "How do I open a .doc file in [Ruby/PHP/OCaml]?" Unfortunately, Objective-C is not one of those languages with a good standard library. In fact, the language itself has essentially nothing but the C standard library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your platform. The iPhone has very different rich text capabilities than OS X. [UIWebView can open them](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2008/qa1630.html) on the iPhone. With Cocoa on Mac OS X, you can just use NSAttributedString.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display it to the user, you can put it in a [`UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). See [this tech note](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2008/qa1630.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView, not only can it display word docs, it can also display:
- Images
- PowerPoints
- Excel
- Any other file (Except project files, like xcodeproj)