# MS Word support on iOS

Tags: ios, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading a .doc (MSWord) file in ObjectiveC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808038/reading-a-doc-msword-file-in-objectivec)

I am writing a printing application that supports to select image and send over Internet for ePrinting.

My client is asking whether it is possible to open MS Word and select/extract some image for above printing method

Is there any way to open MS Word document in my application ? OR is there any third-party (paid is not a problem) for opening and extracting pages in MS Word ?

Thanks.

Comment: Another similar question (without a good answer): [Reading Microsoft word document in iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131430/reading-microsoft-word-document-in-iphone)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [QuickLook.framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuickLook/Reference/QuickLookFrameworkReference_iPhoneOS/_index.html). That can read all MS Office formats. Also can print from a supported AirPrint printer.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to export to PDF, and utilise some image extraction from there.

Useful libraries for this (check which work on iOS)

- Ghostscript
- MuPDF
- Poppler

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source library called [wordview](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wvware/), which you might want to take a look at. It is for MS Word formats up to Word 2000. The newer ones are XML-ish anyway, so you can probably parse them yourself using any XML reader you like.

**Update**: Notice that the license for this library is GPL. Not sure if that is compatible with your requirements.

**Update 2**: The wv2 branch seems to be LGPL, so it should fit all purposes.